# "500 Internal Server Error" received when trying to create a .cgi application from a flask application

Tags: python, flask, cgi

I have created the following Flask application in python (named `simpleflask.py`), using the code below:

```
from flask import Flask
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'This is really unique and secret'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    a = random.randrange(2)
    if a == 1:
        return "<p>the random number selector returned 1</p>"
    else:
        return "<p>the random number selector returned 0</p>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The Flask app runs fine from my personal computer.

I then tried to create a .cgi application using the instructions provided in the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/cgi/), which features the following code:

```
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from simpleflask import app

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

However, it does not work as expected. I keep receiving the following error message:

```
KeyError: 'SERVER_NAME'
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 59

A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

I am not quite sure what this is supposed to mean. Any idea why I am receiving this error? What changes would I have to make to be able to create my .cgi application? Any and all suggestions welcome.

Comment: I don't think .cgi is the way to go. Have a look at the documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/. I would recommend wsgi : http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/

Comment: @Paco Why would you recommend wsgi over .cgi?

Comment: It's not about speed (as the question would suggest, but read the accepted answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747266/is-there-a-speed-difference-between-wsgi-and-fcgi

Answer (score 1):

Your cgi-script has to write firstly headers. At least 'content-type':

```
Content-Type: text/html;
```

with empty line after it.
And then goes your content.

Comment: Before your first prints insert:
`print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"`